# Class Cast Exception being thrown when I use a generic method

Tags: java, arrays, exception, generics, classcastexception

So, I am using 2D arrays for a platformer physics system I'm working on. Unfortunately, the 2D arrays require generic types for various reasons.

I'm dynamically building the surfaces with some java Collections (linkedlist to be precise) and then converting them to 2D arrays with some hacky trickery. This currently works, giving me the appropriate 2D generic array: *

```
LinkedList<PhysSurface<P>> leftSurfaces = new LinkedList<PhysSurface<P>>();
LinkedList<PhysSurface<P>> rightSurfaces = new LinkedList<PhysSurface<P>>();
LinkedList<PhysSurface<P>> topSurfaces = new LinkedList<PhysSurface<P>>();
LinkedList<PhysSurface<P>> bottomSurfaces = new LinkedList<PhysSurface<P>>();

// Add surfaces to the lists

GenericArray<PhysSurface<P>[]> base = new GenericArray<PhysSurface<P>[]>(4);
PhysSurface<P>[][] surfaces = base.elements();
surfaces[0] = leftSurfaces.toArray(new GenericArray<PhysSurface<P>>().elements());
surfaces[1] = rightSurfaces.toArray(new GenericArray<PhysSurface<P>>().elements());
surfaces[2] = topSurfaces.toArray(new GenericArray<PhysSurface<P>>().elements());
surfaces[3] = bottomSurfaces.toArray(new GenericArray<PhysSurface<P>>().elements());
```

However, when I try to put this all into a generic, static method like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T[][] to2DArray(Collection<T>... collections)
{
    GenericArray<T[]> base = new GenericArray<T[]>(collections.length);
    T[][] array = base.elements();
    for(int i = 0; i < collections.length; i++)
        array[i] = collections[i].toArray(new GenericArray<T>().elements());
    return array;
}
```

And then I call the method like this:

```
PhysSurface<P>[][] surfaces = GenericsUtils.to2DArray(leftSurfaces, rightSurfaces, topSurfaces, bottomSurfaces);
```

Then everything crashes, giving me a ClassCastException, saying that it cannot convert type Object to type PhysSurface. The stack trace is here:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [[Lcom.meg.utils._2D.platformer.phys.environment.surface.PhysSurface;
    at com.meg.chaos_temple.test.world.PhysTestWorld$TestMap.<init>(PhysTestWorld.java:487)
    at com.meg.chaos_temple.test.world.PhysTestWorld$TestPlayer.<init>(PhysTestWorld.java:245)
    at com.meg.chaos_temple.test.world.PhysTestWorld.<init>(PhysTestWorld.java:95)
    at com.meg.chaos_temple.main.ChaosDebug.createWorld(ChaosDebug.java:72)
    at com.meg.jrabbit.engine.main.BaseGame.start(BaseGame.java:56)
    at com.meg.jrabbit.engine.loop.Loop.run(Loop.java:44)
    at com.meg.jrabbit.engine.main.BaseGame.run(BaseGame.java:40)
    at com.meg.jrabbit.engine.main.StandardGame.run(StandardGame.java:85)
    at com.meg.chaos_temple.main.ChaosDebug.main(ChaosDebug.java:19)
```

As far as I can tell, the generic method is not using the generic type T, but instead defaulting to creating a Object[][] and attempting to cast up when it returns. If this is what's happening, why does this not work when put into a static method? And if not, what the heck is going on?

---

- (GenericArray is a custom class that uses variable-length arguments to get around the usual barriers to making generic arrays and then wraps the result. The actual constructor is GenericArray(T... elements).)

Comment: Could you please attach stack trace?

Comment: Can you add line numbers to the code examples?  The error is on line 487, but can't see where that is.

Comment: The error occurs when I call the method given above.

Comment: How is `leftSurfaces`'s type defined?

Comment: It's a LinkedList<PhysSurface<P>>. I added that in to the question description.

Comment: `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` hints that `to2DArray` doesn't preserve type information.

Comment: `The actual constructor is GenericArray(T... elements)` that is not how you are using it. You are using `new GenericArray<T[]>(collections.length)`. I would suggest you revisit this and chose the correct constructor. There is probably a constructor like `new GenericArray<T[]>(collections.length, Class clazz)`.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon GenericArray is a class that I wrote. You're correct, the constructor there is taking an int; the actual parameters for that constructor are GenericArray(int minSize, T... elements). It resizes the array to ensure the given minimum size (in this example, I wanted a GenericArray of size 4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately `T[][] array` is the same as `Object[][] array` at run-time. Generic type parameters will be dropped at run-time; only the compiler knows about it.

The solution is to pass the object's class: `Class<T>`.

```
import java.reflect.Array;

...

public static <T> T[][] to2DArray(Class<T> klazz, Collection<T>... collections)
{
    T[][] array = (T[][]) Array.newInstance(klazz, collections.length,
                                                   collections[0].size());
    //...
        array[i] = (T[]) Array.newInstance(klazz, collections[i].size());
    return array;
}
```

The cast of Array.newInstance is necessary for the multidimensional result.
No more `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`!

Instead of passing `collections[0].size()` it probably suffices to pass `0`.

Comment: Will this work for a class with a generic parameter (e.g., PhysSurface<P>)?

Comment: Yes, `Class<PhysSurface<P>>`.